# Strange OpenGL ES 2.0 bug on Galaxy Note 2

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, galaxy

This vertex shader code works on every device except for the *Galaxy Note 2*.
`gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;`
where if I reverse the matrix multiplication to:
`gl_Position = vPosition * uMVPMatrix;` I can actually get things to appear.

Unfortunately, the reverse would require me to completely rewrite my transformations library.

Does anyone have any insight on what could be causing this, is this an opengl driver error with the device?

**Shader code**

```
private final String vertexShaderCode =
    // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
    // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
    "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +

    "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
    "attribute vec2 a_TexCoordinate;" +
    "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;" +
    "void main() {" +
    // the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
    "v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate;" +
    "gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
    "}";

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
    "precision mediump float;" +
    "uniform sampler2D u_Texture;" +
    "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;" +
    "void main() {" +
    "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate);" +
    //"  gl_FragColor = vec4(v_TexCoordinate, 0, 1);" +
    "}";
```

Comment: Do both `vPosition` and `uMVPMatrix` have the same precision?

Comment: keaukraine, thanks for the response. I'm really not sure, if I leave out any precision modifier, does it take some default. I attempted to add "precision mediump float;" + to the vertexShaderCode but it had no effect.

Comment: It can happen on Android devices that different manufactures implement some part of the system differently. I've noticed before that playing music (sound) is a bit different when implementing on HTC or Samsung. It was the same thing with texture size being of power 2, HTC could manage with any texture size while Samsung required them to be of power 2. 
I would suguest that you just do an if statement if there is Samsung phone and use different shader for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about only a galaxy note 2 platform.

This is a mathematical question. Because both glsl/hlsl uses column major order,

It is a right way to multiply MATRIX x VECTOR

or

you can transpose the matrix using  a option in

> > glUniformMatrix4fv( h_Uniforms[UNIFORMS_PROJECTION], 1, **GL_FALSE or GL_TRUE**, g_proxtrans.s);

Apparently, It can be a problem not to call this function with the option ( GL_TRUE is to use transposing ) each every frame just try .